# Change class name of some elements

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change all elements with class `hidden` to class `appeared`. Here's my code:

```
e = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    e[i].className = "appeared";
}
```

Two of three elements that had class named hidden, changed. Why is that? How to solve it? I tried using `getElementById`, it works, but I need to make it general so I can use it for many elements and many classes.

**Edit**

Turns out there is a thread with similar question. I change the code to this and it works:

```
e = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
while (e.length) {
    e[0].className = "appeared";
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `var` or problems will come.

Comment: You should provide a [complete example](http://sscce.org) of your problem, as your current code seems fine (apart from missing `var`s). You can use http://jsfiddle.net or similar sites for this.

Comment: by doing `e[i].className = "appeared";` you remove all other classes as well. I hope you're aware of that? Consider modifying the `classList` instead.

Comment: thanks, I use this code and everything works
        `while (e.length) {
            e[0].className = "appeared";
        }`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`, which is a [live collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList#Description). Thus, every time you asked for its length, the collection is recalculated. Since you have already changed the className for some elements, the loop ends earlier than you expected.

If you check the values for `i` and `length` for each loop, you will have:

- The first time, length is 3. (0 < 3) is **true**, so it changes its class.
- The second time, length is 2. (1 < 2) is **true**, so it changes its class.
- The first time, length is 1. (2 < 1) is **false**. It doesn't change its class.

You should convert the NodeList to an array:

```
var e = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("hidden"));
```

Or you can use the alternative code you provided, although in that case the selection is recalculated every time you ask for its length property.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jQuery and use the show() and hide() methods:

To show all elements with classname 'hidden':

```
$('.hidden').show();
```

To hide all elements with classname 'hidden':

```
$('.hidden').hide();
```

To include jQuery add this script at the end of your body tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's for a school project and no library is allowed, yes it's like reinventing the wheel but this way student will explore more about the language, my TA said.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your original code failed is because `getElementsByClassName` returns a **live view** on the elements with the class `hidden`. Therefore, when you change the class of an element inside your loop, this change is reflected in the view and that element will no longer be in there.

Here's an example scenario:

1. `e` initially contains 3 `hidden` elements.
2. In the first iteration, `i == 0` and `e[0]` is changed to be *no longer* `hidden`. This means that `e` now only contains 2 `hidden` elements, as the 'old' `e[0]` is removed.
3. In the second iteration, `i` is already at `1` but `e[0]` is *still* a `hidden` element. This means that you'll skip over `e[0]` (which was `e[1]` before the loop). In this iteration, you'll remove the class of `e[1]` (which was `e[2]` previously) and the view is reduced to 1 element.
4. Since `i` (= 2) now exceeds `e.length` (= 1), the loop terminates.

The net result is that you skipped over the old `e[1]`. There are two ways to tackle this problem:

- Make `e` static by copying its contents to another array first. This is the approach most libraries such as jQuery take.
- Make use of the *liveness*. As you showed in your edit, you can use the live collection to your advantage. By always operating on the *currently* first element in the view, you'll never skip over any element. The loop condition is also trivial: you just have to keep iterating until the view no longer contains any elements.